# How can I get CSS Intellisense to work in .scss files, in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, sass

We'd been using Mindscape's Web Workbench plugin for some time in VS 2010. It's pretty nice. However, upon installing Visual Studio 2012, we noticed that CSS Intellisense is no longer working in .scss files.

That is to say, if I type in

```
.myStyle {
   display: 
}
```

I expect an Intellisense dropdown after "display:" to show me options like "block", "none", etc. But I only see the SASS completion options, no CSS options. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension
2. Add the extension "scss" and associate it with "CSS Source Editor"
3. Go down to Tools > Options > Text Editor > CSS
4. Check the box under Statement Completion for "Auto list members"

This will give you CSS completion, but unfortunately it looks like you'll no longer get autocomplete for SASS stuff. So pick your poison until somebody comes along with a better answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, 2010 didn't include the CSS Source Editor for extension associations. OP wanted 2012, but I guess us 2010-ers need to revert to MindScape in lieu.